# Cross browser compablity jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

right now I am studying jquery. So far I have learned a lot of new functions that solve cross browser compablity problems you have when using plain javascript. For example the $(document).ready() method. If the browser supports DOMContentLoaded, the jquery scrpt will fire that event. However if the browser does not support that event, jquery will  the fire the second best option, the load event. I have noticed though that a lot of other javascript objects and functions that also do have cross browser compablity issues, dont have a special way of writing them in jquery. For example the event.target property, or even the event object as a whole. There is a different way of writing them in for example IE 7 and IE 9.In javascript, this can be fixed by adding some if/else statements and  maybe some logical operators.In Jquery there is no special way of wrting the event object a and its properties. So my question is whether jquery does this automatically for you when you have a jquery link in your html.

Comment: jQuery covers most common cross-browser issues. That said, I don't know any devs still worrying about IE7 compatibility. The new Bootstrap v4 won't even support IE9. If you have *specific* concerns, open a question on them - this question is overly broad.

Comment: yeah I wouldn't even worry about supporting IE7 and lower...god knows I don't

Comment: https://jquery.com/browser-support/